# How to make a Discord Bot (NodeJS App) in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: node.js, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, discord.js

I tried for the last 3 - 4 months trying to know how i could make a NodeJS Application or A DiscordJS Bot in A .NET Windows Form Application, And i have not gotten a way to make it, I Have Full knowledge of Node and JS but don't how to connect it to a windows form application, is there any way to do that?

When i am saying a discord Bot, i mean a normal NodeJS App with code that looks like this:

```
const Variable;
let Variable;
var Variable;

let this = new Variable.Snowflake();
```

Comment: Do you want to make a .NET application, or a NodeJS application ? You can't do both, at least not in the same 'project' (in visual studio terms).

Comment: I am trying t make a discord bot in Windows Form Application, so anything that allows bots for Discord in .NET is welcomed.